# Why member variables of a const object are not const

Tags: c++, reference, constants, c++14, decltype

Just asked a similar question which boils down to this one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() : a{1} {};
    int a;
};

template <typename Which>
struct WhichType;

int main() {
    const A a;
    const A& a_ref = a;
    const A* a_ptr = &a;
    WhichType<decltype(a.a)> which_obj; // template evaluates to int
    WhichType<decltype(a_ref.a)> which_ref; // template evaluates to int
    WhichType<decltype(a_ptr->a)> which_ptr; // template evaluates to int

    return 0;
}
```

Why do the templates do not become `const int` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`decltype` gives you the "declared type" of the operand when it isn't enclosed in an extra set of parentheses.

To get the actual type of the expression, that is, `const int`, you would have to write `decltype((a.a))` and so on.

`decltype` always returns a reference type for lvalue expressions other than names.

Comment: So `decltype` **always** returns only the type of the declaration of the name as defined in code?  Ignoring the `const`ness, `ref`ness or `volatile`ness of all objects taken to get there?  for example a variable within a `const` object?

Comment: @Curious For the specific case where the operand is just the name of a variable or a member access expression, yes, it gives the type of the declaration. The cv-qualification of the enclosing object modifies the type of the expression but you only get the type of the expression if you use extra parentheses. A similar thing applies for value category.

Answer (score 2):

When passed the name of an identifier (or member), it returns the type of declaration.

When passed a different expression, it returns something closer to what you want, but reference-qualified.

```
WhichType<std::remove_reference_t<decltype((a_ptr->a))>> which_ptr; // template evaluates to const int!
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49848d7c862a4c0f)
or if you want the l/r valueness:

```
WhichType<decltype((a_ptr->a))> which_ptr2; // template evaluates to const int&
WhichType<decltype(((const A){}.a))> which_ptr3; // template evaluates to const int
```

you can append `&&` to make it a "real" rvalue reference here.

```
WhichType<decltype(((A){}.a))&&> which_ptr4; // template evaluates to int&&!
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e283ee4a77e3cf0).

Comment: That's great!  I saw this method used in Scott Meyer's C++ book so I didn't even think about it when using it.  Is there anything else I should know about `decltype` other than this subtlety?

Comment: You can use `std::declval<const A>()` instead of `(const A){}`

Comment: @jarrod sure, but that is longer!

Comment: `(const A){}` would fail if `A` is not default constructible, and I would argue it is less readable.

Comment: @oka yes, but `A` is default constructible.  And `std::declval<A>()` is only more readable to template library programmers or hobbiests.  ;)

Comment: Last time I checked, `(const A){}` is a C99 compound literal, not standard C++. Also, class member access on a prvalue is supposed to yield an xvalue (for a non-reference, non-static data member), though apparently your compiler hasn't gotten to implementing that DR yet.